# My application crashes when I try to parse a string

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am trying to parse a string to calculate a total of my products' price but when I use "Integer.parseInt" my application crashes.
 I know that I have to initialize a string array caused the instruction "Integer.parseInt" can not parse a NULL but I don't know how exactly the problem is my array element comes from splitting an string. please help me guys...
My code:

```java
    class Thread2 implements Runnable {//recieve
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    final String message = input.readLine();
                    if (message != null) {
                        owner.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                String[] a = message.split("\\#");
                                int n = a.length;
                                    for(int i=1;i<n;i++){

                                        String[]    b =a[i].split("\\*");

                                             tee.append(b[0]+"                    "+b[1]+"\n");
                                             y.append(b[1]+"*");

                                             P1=Integer.parseInt(b[1]);

                                             //total = total+p1[i];


                                    }



                                te.setText(Integer.toString(total));



                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        Thread myThred = new Thread(new Thread21());
                        myThred.start();
                        return;
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `te.setText(""+Integer.toString(total));`

Comment: please write value for message  so we can debug your code.

Comment: You need to check if the b array's length is at least 2 before getting index 0 and 1. Most probably you are having an IndexOutOfBoundsException. Also what is y? Is it initialised? Sharing the crash stacktrace would be helpful.

Comment: print all the Strings before and after splitting.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your English. Could you please reword and use some punctuation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use `try-catch` to handle the exception inside ui block.

```
    try {
        String[]    b =a[i].split("\\*");

        tee.append(b[0]+"                    "+b[1]+"\n");
        y.append(b[1]+"*");

        P1=Integer.parseInt(b[1]);

        //total = total+p1[i];
    } catch(Exception ex) {
    }
```

Besides this, you could use **`Exception`** in your `catch` block rather than **`IOException`** to handle all kind of exception and avoid crash. Thanks

Edit like:

```
     } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Instead of:

```
     } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. By default use value 0 for P1 and only take value from b[1] when the array is having value at b[1] and it is not null.

```
P1 = 0;
if(b.length() > 1){
    if(b[1] != null)
        P1=Integer.parseInt(b[1]);
}
....
```